# Passing a function to d3's .data()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, callback, transition

This [suburst with updating data](http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/477c1bfb081b783f80ad) makes a call `path.data(partition.value(value).nodes)`, where `partition` is a `d3.layout.partition` with the `value()` function used to layout the `nodes`. Initially, data is passed to `path` through `svg.datum(root)`, but in both the first call and on the `input` change, only the function `partition.nodes` is passed to `data()`.

I am assuming `data()` then just accesses what is already bound to the element, but I wanted clarification, as `path` is defined as the `enter` group, how exactly this is done behind the scenes. Thank you! Code excerpt below.

```
var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return 1; });

d3.json("/d/4063550/flare.json", function(error, root) {
  node = root;
  var path = svg.datum(root).selectAll("path")
      .data(partition.nodes)
    .enter().append("path")
     ...


  d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {
    var value = this.value === "count"
        ? function() { return 1; }
        : function(d) { return d.size; };

    path
        .data(partition.value(value).nodes)
      .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", arcTweenData);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand what's happening here, it's useful to have a look at the [nested selection](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) tutorial. Although it's not the same kind of use case here, this is technically what it is -- the initial data is passed on to the later call to `.data()`.

The general pattern for nested selections is `.data(function(d) { return ...; })`. This is what's happening here as well; the long version of the above code would be

```
path.data(function(d) { return partition.value(value).nodes(d); })
```

where `d` is the data bound to the parent node, `root`.

Comment: I understand that the original call and the `onchange` call are essentially equivalent, just with a change in the accessor. My question is that even on the initial call `data(partition.nodes)`, `partition.nodes` is a function that does indeed return an array, but no data is directly passed to it. I am asking about the apparent implicit data passing from `svg.datum(root)`. Thank you!

Comment: Apologies, I was unclear (and actually mistaken about the details!) -- I've fixed this and hope that it answers your question now.